# Polar set of convex hull

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I would like to prove that the polar set of the convex hull of $\{u^i\}_1^k$ is
$
(co\{u^i\}_1^k)^*=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \langle x,u^i\rangle\leq 1, i=1,...,k\}. 
$

Can anybody help me? I've tried so many times with representing $u$ as $\lambda u_i+(1-\lambda)u_j$, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle x,u^i\rangle\leq1$ for all $i$, then for any convex combination you have
$$
\Big\langle x,\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u^i\Big\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\,\langle x,u^i\rangle\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1.
$$
And the converse is trivial: if $\langle x,y\rangle\leq1$ for any $y$ which is a convex combination of the $u^i$, you can in particular take $y=u^i$.